# gridelement: freezing backend when opening new content element wizard

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-gridelements

we have the problem that the complete Backend of TYPO3 is freezing when adding a new content element to a gridelement.

What we do:
adding new content element in a gridelement - opening the new content element wizard which remains empty. After a few seconds the whole backend freezes. Only possibility is releading the backend.

TYPO3 9.5.18 and 9.5.20
Gridelements 9.1.1

Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please update your Gridelements version and check if this fixes the problem for you? GE 9.1.1 is quite old

Comment: Hi Jo, updating fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to newest version which runs on TYPO3 9 fixes the problem.